# confused about proposal distribution in MCMC

Tags: normal-distribution, markov-chains, monte-carlo

This is a question from notes
[image]

I have some questions regarding the proposal distribution which is $N(x,1)$

1. Is the proposal distribution symmetric i.e. $g(x_p|x)=g(x|x_p)$?
2. I'm not sure whether it is correct: let's x=0 first, and rand() in excel gives 0.95 as culumative probability so $x_p=1.64$ and $g(1.64|0)=0.95$, but how come $g(0|1.64)$=$g(1.64|0)=0.95$?

This is a binomial example

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes: the normal distribution cares only about the distance between the mean and the point. Note that in $g(x \mid x_p)$, the mean is $x_p$ now, not $x$, so the distance between the mean in the two cases are the same and the variance in the two cases are the same. (In this symmetric situation, the algorithm is commonly called just Metropolis, rather than Metropolis-Hastings.)
2. The $f$ in the formula is the PDF of the desired sampling distribution, not the CDF. (In a discrete problem it would be the PMF, not the CDF.) The same is true of $g$, although because of the symmetry, $g$ will simply cancel out anyway.

By the way, because the shape of your distribution is much like a normal distribution with variance $1/2$, not $1$, you will probably get better performance if your sampling uses a variance $1/2$ normal r.v. rather than $1$. (That said, in general choosing the candidate distribution is more art than science: it needs to be "adventurous" enough to efficiently explore the configuration space, "conservative" enough that most jumps are accepted, and computationally tractable to draw many samples from it.)

Comment: and the note says that "The basic idea is to construct a Markov Chain whose equilibrium distribution is equal to the problematic
distribution and simulating the chain until equilibrium.",, so in this case, what's the equilibrium for f(y)and g(y)?

Comment: In Metropolis-Hastings, the target distribution (with the given pdf $f$) is the equilibrium distribution. This is easiest to prove by proving something that is actually stronger, namely that MH satisfies the detailed balance condition: if $p(x,y)$ denotes the (generalized) transition density from $x$ to $y$ (i.e. $g(y|x)$ times the acceptance probability) then $f(x) p(x,y)=f(y) p(y,x)$. You can look up proofs that if a Markov process satisfies the detailed balance condition with respect to some distribution then that distribution is stationary.

Comment: This is very easy to check in the context of discrete space (it is just a linear algebra problem), but it is a bit more complicated in the case of continuous space like your problem.

Comment: How can I come up with a proposal distribution whose equilibrium distribution is equal original $f$? For example, let's say $X\sim Bin(10,0.3)$, what's the possible proposal distribution $g(x)$ that has the same equilibrium distribution as $f(x)=\binom{10}{x}0.3^x0.7^{(1-x)}$? And how to calculate transition probability $p(x,y)$ ? For example, what's the value of $p(3,4)?$

Comment: Provided the target distribution is absolutely continuous with respect to your candidate distribution (roughly speaking, any possible value in the target distribution can eventually occur in the sampling procedure), MH provides the correction needed to ensure that the overall Markov chain you construct has the desired equilibrium distribution. You only need to worry about picking a good candidate distribution for performance reasons.

Comment: In your binomial example, you could (if you really wanted to) take your sampling scheme to be something like independent uniform sampling on ${0,\dots,10} $, or going left or right with equal probability. The only necessity would be that all 11 values can be attained by the candidate distribution.

Comment: I have edit my question to include a binomial example. So if the proposal distribution $q$ which is $q_{i,j}=\frac{1}{12}$, but $q$'s equilibrium distribution is not equal to $f(x)$. Do I have a misunderstanding at a PDF's equilibrium distribution?

Comment: To sample from Bin (10,0.3), you can start with $q_i=1/11$ for $i=0,1,\dots,10$. But then you accept a move from I to j with probability $\min \{ 1,f (j)/f (i)\}$ where $f $ is the PMF. This changes the equilibrium distribution of the overall chain that you construct. In particular, transitions from 3 or 4 will tend to be rare while transitions from 0 or 10 will almost always be accepted. (Not sure why your example suggests including 11 in the candidate distribution; all those attempts will just be rejected anyway).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42745/discussion-between-whoisit-and-ian).

Comment: I think I have some misunderstanding at some basic stuff. I'm not sure if these are correct: 1.Before the sampling,The equilibrium distribution of q is 11 states, each with a probabiity of 1/11. 2.After the long run with the acceptance method, these 11 states will be the same distribution as original bin $f(x)$? 2. why transitions from 3 or 4 will tend to be rare while transitions from 0 or 10 will almost always be accepted?

Comment: So there is one Markov chain, call it $X_n$ which consists of independent identically distributed random variables which are equal to any given element of $\{ 0,\dots,10 \}$ with probability $1/11$. Your MH Markov chain is not this one. Instead, your Markov chain goes like this: given the value $Y_n$, $Y_{n+1}$ is equal to $X_{n+1}$ with probability $\min \{ 1,\frac{f(X_{n+1})}{f(Y_n)} \}$ and otherwise it is equal to $Y_n$. (Note that the candidate distribution in this case is again symmetric.)

Comment: $Y_n$ is quite different from $X_n$. For example, when $Y_n=3$, the probability of accepting any transition except to $2,3$ or $4$ is less than $1/2$. (I checked this by just running binopdf(0:10,10,0.3)/binopdf(3,10,0.3) in Matlab.)That means that in this chain, when you arrive at $3$, you tend to stay there for a little while. That's a good thing, because $3$ has a probability of about $0.26$ in the target distribution, which is considerably higher than $1/11 \approx 0.09$.

Comment: On the other hand, doing basically the same calculation shows us that when $Y_n=10$, *any* transition will be accepted with probability $1$. This makes sense because $10$ is the least likely of all the $11$ states in the target distribution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I really got a lot from it. One thing I'm still not sure when you says $Y_{n+1}$ is equal to $X_{n+1}$ with probability min$\left \{ 1,\frac{f(X_{n+1})}{f(Y_{n})} \right \}$ and otherwise it is equal to $Y_{n}$, don't we need to use rand() to simulate a variable $u$ of U[0,1], when $u<min\left \{ 1,\frac{f(X_{n+1})}{f(Y_{n})} \right \}$ that's when we accept the move?

Comment: That's just how you implement "$Y_{n+1}=X_{n+1}$ with probability $\min \{ 1,\frac{f(X_{n+1})}{f(Y_n)} \}$", since $u$ is less than some fixed number $p \in [0,1]$ with probability $p$.