# confused about the proof of Markov chain Monte Carlo

Tags: probability, markov-chains, sampling, monte-carlo, transition-matrix

This is the proof from notes[image]

I'm confused about the $\pi(x_p|x)$ and $\pi(x|x_p)$

Let's say $X\sim $**Bin**$(10,0.3)$, so $\pi(x)=\binom{10}{x}0.3^x0.7^{(10-x)}$, so what does  $\pi(x_p|x)$ or $\pi(x|x_p)$ mean? It doesn't make any sense, for example what's the value of $\pi(4|3)$?

If I got a misunderstanding on $\pi(x)$, could you provide an example with values to show why $\pi(x_p|x)$ is meaningful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation is overloaded here - $\pi(x_p|x)$ is not related (directly) to $\pi(x)$, and arguably it would be clearer to replace $\pi(x_p|x)$ with some other notation, such as $q(x_p|x)$. The "constructing a Markov chain" referred to in your text means *choosing* a transition distribution $q(x_p|x)$ so that the stated condition holds. So you could, for example, choose something like

$q(x_p|x) = 0.5$ if $x_p \equiv x \pm 1 \mod 10$   and $q(x_p|x) = 0$ otherwise.

This example corresponds to a "random walk" transition distribution over the state space $\{1,\ldots,10\}$ (with wrapping at the boundaries). It turns out this will not satisfy the stated condition; the text is describing a way in which to choose a transition distribution $q(x_p|x)$ so that the condition $\pi(x)q(x_p|x) = \pi(x_p)q(x|x_p)$ will be satisfied. This method is known as the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm.

This kind of overloading of notation is not uncommon in the computational statistics literature, and it's definitely something to be aware of.

Comment: can you provide an example where $q$ is a binomial distribution because I have a binomial example in this post http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1864363/confused-about-proposal-distribution-in-mcmc/1864376?noredirect=1#comment3820444_1864376

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking here - can you phrase your question more specifically? The point of MCMC is that if the target distribution $\pi(x)$ is e.g. a binomial distribution, we don't necessarily have to take the transition distribution $q(x_p|x)$ to be a binomial as well - this allows us to generate samples from complicated distributions by generating samples from simpler distributions.

Comment: what I want to understand now is how come $\pi(x)\pi(x_p|x)=\pi(x_p)\pi(x|x_p)$?Is it true for any markov chains which are ergodic and aperiodic? The text says "we start by constructing a markov chain, making it $\pi(x)\pi(x_p|x)=\pi(x_p)\pi(x|x_p)$...
But how can we prove for any any markov chains which are ergodic and aperiodic, we have $\pi(x)\pi(x_p|x)=\pi(x_p)\pi(x|x_p)$?